# Confidence Interval after linear regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to get the confidence interval after fitting the linear regression model.
My data contains:

```
Growthrate  Strains
<dbl>       <fct>
```

where growthrate represents growthrate value and Strains represents strain names

my code:

```
all.lm <- lm(Growthrate~Strains,all) 

confint(all.lm, 'Strains',level=0.95)
```

Output:

```
          2.5 % 97.5 %  
Strains    NA     NA
```

I don't understand why its printing NA.
Any help at this point is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Strains` is a categorical variable so there is no coefficient called `Strains`. Here is an example using the `iris` data set that is included with R:

```
data(iris)
iris.lm <- lm(Petal.Width~Species, iris)
confint(iris.lm, level=.95)   # All coefficients
#                       2.5 %    97.5 %
# (Intercept)       0.1888041 0.3031959
# Speciesversicolor 0.9991128 1.1608872
# Speciesvirginica  1.6991128 1.8608872

confint(iris.lm, "Species", level=.95)  # Species is not a coefficient
#         2.5 % 97.5 %
# Species    NA     NA
```

You need to specify the coefficients by name or number:

```
confint(iris.lm, 2:3, level=.95)
#                       2.5 %   97.5 %
# Speciesversicolor 0.9991128 1.160887
# Speciesvirginica  1.6991128 1.860887

cfnames <- names(coef(iris.lm))[2:3]
cfnames
# [1] "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica" 
confint(iris.lm, cfnames, level=.95)
#                       2.5 %   97.5 %
# Speciesversicolor 0.9991128 1.160887
# Speciesvirginica  1.6991128 1.860887
```

Actually `(Intercept)` in this example is the coefficient for `Speciessetosa`, the first factor level, so it would make sense to include this coefficient as well.

Comment: Thank you that make sense. I am asking more basic question so here confidence interval is for all levels example Speciesversicolor, Speciesvirginica etc. So when you report this value do you report it asfor individual explanatory variables or there is a way to get overal l confidence interval?

Comment: There is not one overall confidence interval. If we change the analysis to predicting `lm(Petal.Width~Petal.Length, iris)`, there will still be separate confidence intervals for the y-intercept and the coefficient for the independent variable (Petal.Length). Using `predict(iris.lm, interval="confidence")` you can get confidence intervals for each observation.